# Git commit comes as myname authored and myname committed 20 min ago. Name is coming two times in commit . how to make it appear only once?

Tags: git

Git commit comes as my name authored and my name committed 20 min ago. Name is coming two times in commit. how to make it appear only once?

Comment: By two times, do you mean the author name and the committer name? If so, it's working as designed. The author and the committer could be different persons.

Comment: How can I remove one of these?

Answer (score 1):

All commits have an author and a committer.

A "regular commit" has the same name+email in both ; some actions, like `git commit --amend`, `git cherry-pick` or`git rebase` keep the author of the original commit, and update the committer.

That part is the standard behavior of git.

As for what is *displayed*, this depends on the tool you use to view commits :

- `git log` in the terminal can be tweaked by a lot of options
- graphical viewers have configuration options which you can explore
- online tools like `github` or `bitbucket` will have limited customization of their "log" view
- etc ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you see those two information.

A simple git log would only display the author for instance.
Only a `git log --pretty="full"` would show both author and committer.
Which, in your case, would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same situation which the OP faced (GitHub screenshot attached), where the "author" name and the "committed" name was showing up separately.[image]

I was able to fix it by running this command mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/amalmurali47/77e8dc1f27c791729518701d2dec3680).

**Please note that running the command below can potentially change the author and committed information of ALL the commits in the remote repository**

Copy-pasting the command in case the link doesn't work :-

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
EMAIL="your.email@email.com"
NAME="your_username"

export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$EMAIL"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$EMAIL"'
```

Then run :-

```
git push origin +<branch_name> # note the plus before the branch name
```

In my case I ran the command :-

```
git push origin +main
```